# Is there a PHP unless function?

Tags: php, if-statement

Not a PHP programmer, but I am trying to write a bit of code for my project.

I don't know how to write this PHP statement properly. Assuming I have 3 elements a,b,c from different mysql columns.

```
if(a > b) $dump->out('Message 1') unless a > c;
```

Not sure "if else" applies here

Comment: No `else` needed, there are simply 2 conditions that need to be matched.

Comment: this may well be best done in the query itself (never select more data than you  use)

Comment: `unless a > c` means if `a > c` then don't do it. So just do it when ***not*** `a > c`, in other words when `a <= c`. So just combine that condition to your current condition, you'll have the right code.

Comment: did not expect a solution that fast, not sure how to accept the answer either. I apologize for my next question. "unless a > c" is supposed to cancel the whole php line if the condition is not met. does that still apply?

Comment: @JohnSmith If you don't use curly braces (`{}`) with your if statement (and you really should - for readability at least) then the if statement will apply to the whole line. Basically that means until the first semi-colon. You can accept an answer by clicking the green tick below the down vote button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to think about your condition.

```
if($a > $b && $a <= $c) {
    $dump->out('Message 1');
}
```

Essentially you are asking if "A" is greater than "B", but **not** greater than "C".

You could write: `if($a > $b && !($a > $c))` but I think for better readability, just changing the statement to be "A" is greater than "B" and "A" is less than or equal to "C" is better.

`$a <= $c` is the same as `!($a > $c)`

Answer (score 0):

Use following condition

```
if($a > $b && $a < $c) {
    $dump->out('Message 1');
}
```

always try to use single line statement
you can also try ternary condition like:

```
($a > $b) && ($a < $c) ? $dump->out('Message 1') : '' ;
```